# Weird Interleaving requirement

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a log table that contains (to be simple), user, operation, date.
There are two operations: search and view (search may return a hundred records; the user may view zero or more).

I need to have the basic output sorted by date, but I also need to have all of the views for one search together. Something like

```
 name    operation     date
 john    search        1/1 1pm
 john    view          1/1 2pm
 john    view          1/1 3pm
 james   search        1/1 230pm
 james   view          1/1 315pm
 john    search        1/1 310pm
```

It seems I need to use the results of a subquery to perform the query, but I'm not sure how that would look. I'm OK with SQL but I kind of hit the ceiling with JOINs and UNIONs. :-/

Comment: It's not clear to me what you want to do.

Comment: Read this.  https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1):

You can identify the groups by using a window function.  And you can include the window function in the `order by`, so no subqueries are needed.

```
select *
from log_table l
order by max(case when l.operation = 'search' then l.log_date end) over (partition by l.name order by l.log_date),
         l.name,
         l.log_date;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=5fcb21be84ef5d6a73fa68c45af542ad) is a db<>fiddle.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a conditional `lag()` call to find the most recent search date/time for each view row, per user; with search rows getting their own date/time:

```
-- CTE for sample data
with log_table (name, operation, log_date) as (
            select 'john', 'search', timestamp '2019-01-01 13:00:00' from dual
  union all select 'john', 'view', timestamp '2019-01-01 14:00:00' from dual
  union all select 'john', 'view', timestamp '2019-01-01 15:00:00' from dual
  union all select 'james', 'search', timestamp '2019-01-01 14:30:00' from dual
  union all select 'james', 'view', timestamp '2019-01-01 15:15:00' from dual
  union all select 'john', 'search', timestamp '2019-01-01 15:10:00' from dual
)
-- actual query
select name, operation, log_date,
  case when operation = 'search' then log_date
       else  lag(case when operation = 'search' then log_date end ignore nulls)
               over (partition by name order by log_date)
  end as search_date
from log_table
order by log_date;

NAME  OPERATION LOG_DATE            SEARCH_DATE        
----- --------- ------------------- -------------------
john  search    2019-01-01 13:00:00 2019-01-01 13:00:00
john  view      2019-01-01 14:00:00 2019-01-01 13:00:00
james search    2019-01-01 14:30:00 2019-01-01 14:30:00
john  view      2019-01-01 15:00:00 2019-01-01 13:00:00
john  search    2019-01-01 15:10:00 2019-01-01 15:10:00
james view      2019-01-01 15:15:00 2019-01-01 14:30:00
```

You can then use that as a CTE or inline view, and use the generated `search_date` to order first, then order the records with the same search date by their actual log date:

```
-- CTE for sample data
with log_table (name, operation, log_date) as (
            select 'john', 'search', timestamp '2019-01-01 13:00:00' from dual
  union all select 'john', 'view', timestamp '2019-01-01 14:00:00' from dual
  union all select 'john', 'view', timestamp '2019-01-01 15:00:00' from dual
  union all select 'james', 'search', timestamp '2019-01-01 14:30:00' from dual
  union all select 'james', 'view', timestamp '2019-01-01 15:15:00' from dual
  union all select 'john', 'search', timestamp '2019-01-01 15:10:00' from dual
)
-- actual query
select name, operation, log_date
from (
  select name, operation, log_date,
    case when operation = 'search' then log_date
         else  lag(case when operation = 'search' then log_date end ignore nulls)
                 over (partition by name order by log_date)
    end as search_date
  from log_table
)
order by search_date, log_date;

NAME  OPERATION LOG_DATE           
----- --------- -------------------
john  search    2019-01-01 13:00:00
john  view      2019-01-01 14:00:00
john  view      2019-01-01 15:00:00
james search    2019-01-01 14:30:00
james view      2019-01-01 15:15:00
john  search    2019-01-01 15:10:00
```

As you could potentially get simultaneous searches from two users, you might want to include the user in the final order-by clause too:

```
...
order by search_date, name, log_date;
```

Comment: . . You might find my answer interesting.

Comment: Yes, I thought I'd over-complicated it but couldn't immediately think how to do it in one, and was in a rush *8-)